# Google Sign in API OAuth2 error: "invalid_request" with youtube scope

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth

Google Sign In API OAuth2 works fine when I choose a user account. But During authorization with youtube scope user is also able to choose between Brand account and User Account. In case of Brand account was chose error appears.

```
type: "tokenFailed"
idpId: "google"
error: "server_error"
```

For authentication I use next google libraries

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=init" async defer></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" async defer onload="console.log('api loaded')"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
 GOOGLE_AUTH = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    GOOGLE_AUTH.signIn()
      .then(() => {
        window.gapi.load('client');
        window.gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
        return window.gapi.client.load(SCOPE);
    })
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference